# Why does R `stringr::str_extract('word. 42', pattern = '\\d*')` not produce `"42"`?

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have a vector of strings of the form "letters numbers", I want to extract the numbers using RegEx implemented in `stringr::str_extract` with pattern `"\\d*"`. The results are very confusing:

```
# R 4.2.3
# install.packages('stringr')
library(stringr)

# case 1
str_extract('word 42', '\\d*')
# ""

# case 2 (?)
str_extract('42 word', '\\d*')
# "42"

# case 3
str_extract('word 42', '\\d+')
# "42"

# case 4 (?!)
str_extract('word 42', '\\d*$')
# "42"

# case 5
str_extract('42 word', '\\d*$')
# ""
```

In all the cases the expected result is `"42"`.
I am a novice with RegEx's, but the `pattern = '\\d*'` seems pretty straightforward - I understand it as "match any number of consecutive numeric characters".

The fact that it doesn't work for case 1 but does for case 2 is quite counterintuitive by itself. And then the roles seem to be reversed when using `pattern = '\\d*$'` (cases 4 and 5).

I have experimented more with other functions (`str_match` and `str_match_all`), but the results where still not clear.

I couldn't find such a specific thing elsewhere, so I hoped more experienced R/RegEx users could provide a clarification on what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I understand it as "match any number of consecutive numeric characters".

Any number *including zero*. And it will match at the *first position* where the pattern succeeds. Because `\d*` can successfully match zero digits, it will never look anywhere besides the beginning of the string. If there are no digits there, then you get `""`.

Most likely, you want `\d+` instead, which matches *one or more* digits. Then, the match will fail at positions where there aren't any digits, and you will get the first string of digits in the string.

But `\d*$` works for you in case 4 because, again, it's looking for the *first position* where there are zero or more digits followed by end of string. It could match zero digits at the end of string, but it doesn't get a chance to because it finds the position right before the `42` before it finds the position right at the end of the string. In case 5 there are no digits at the end of the string so it has to wait until the end, where it can successfully match zero digits.

Comment: *facepalm* Quite embarassing to be honest, more reasons not to work at nights. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgePak it's a pretty common mistake. We don't tend to account for the fact that a pattern can succeed and yet match nothing.